# SOAP request deconstruction

Tags: soap, parameters, definition

What does Envelope refer to in this soap request?

```
OST /InStock HTTP/1.1 Host: www.example.org Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: nnn

<?xml version="1.0"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">   <m:GetStockPrice>
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>   </m:GetStockPrice> </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have no idea what  you're asking. Do you simply not know what a SOAP envelope is?